# How can I use the JQuery Autocomplet UI with data from a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, autocomplete, xmlhttprequest

I'm able to get the JSON data with a `XMLHttpRequest` but how can I use this request as data for my autocomplete?

```
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET', url);

ourRequest.onload = function() {
    var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    renderHTML(ourData);
};

ourRequest.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the `source` parameter to give autocomplete values, Here is an example:

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
});
```

Here availableTags is your json data
You can check this [link](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) for complete description.